# Set position of 3D-object with GLSL in WebGL project

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, glsl, webgl, glsles

I'm trying to accomplish position setting with GLSL language.

First of all, when I saw such lines:

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

void main( void ) {
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4( aVertexPosition, 1.0 );
}
```

I thought, that I could set `aVertexPosition` from the function input.
Also, I'm using GLSL 1.2 ( which is used by OpenGL ES and so by WebGL too ), and the project is web one with using JavaScript/WebGL.

I have said this information for future questions from your side possibly, but as I think, it doesn't matter **EXACTLY** for this situation, what is the main application logic language ( C++ or JS ), because the trouble occurred exactly in shading part, not with the logic one of application.

So... Back to the code lines... When I saw the lines above, I thought, that I could change it to the such way:

```
ClassName.prototype.createShaderVs = function( objectPosition ) {
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.id = 'shader-vs';
    script.type = 'x-shader/x-vertex';
    script.text = 'varying vec3 aVertexPosition;\
                    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;\
                    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;\
                    void main( void ) {\
                        aVertexPosition = vec3('
                           + objectPosition.x + ','
                           + objectPosition.y + ','
                           + objectPosition.z + ');\
                        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4( aVertexPosition, 1.0 );\
                    }';
    document.head.appendChild( script );
};
```

But, when I tried to execute such a logic, I've got errors in console:

[image]

Why did I think that it could work?
Because when I tried the similar thing for `fragment-shader`, when I set the color for mesh, it works pretty fine:

```
ClassName.prototype.createShaderFs = function( colorSchema ) {
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.id = 'shader-fs';
    script.type = 'x-shader/x-fragment';
    script.text = 'precision mediump float;\
                    void main( void ) {\
                        gl_FragColor = vec4('
                            + colorSchema.r + ','
                            + colorSchema.g + ','
                            + colorSchema.b + ','
                            + colorSchema.a + ');\
                    }';
    document.head.appendChild( script );
};
```

So the setting color with the `fragment-shader` does work, but with settings the position in `vertex-shader` - doesn't, why?

Also, I thought, that logic with position setting via GLSL mustn't look like that, but it's only my suggestion.

There is also a way to set position not from GLSL, but from the JS part:

```
mat4.identity( object3d.mvMatrix );
mat4.translate( object3d.mvMatrix, [ 0, 0.0, -7.0 ] );
```

But I wonder exactly about setting it via GLSL langauge, if it's possible.
Because I'm preparing OO-solution for my program, and want users, who will use my library be able to set the position of object from the constructor, like:

```
var triangle = new Triangle({
    position: { x: inputX, y: inputY; z: inputZ },
    ...etc...
});
this.scene.add( triangle );
```

Answer (score 0):

You obviously don't fully understand how shaders work.

Vertex shader is called once for each vertex,
and input to the vertex shader stage are *attributes* of the current vertex.

Fragment shader is called once for each fragment,
and input to the fragment shader stage are *varying* variables, which are always calculated and interpolated (from the attributes of the polygon that make up primitive which current fragment is a part of) for the currently processed fragment.

Both shader stages can use *uniform* variables, those are variables that don't change per-vertex/per-fragment, but are *uniform* (same) across all of them.

---

So, let me try to explain why the code you've written is impossible to work.

You create vertex shader and compile it, then create fragment shader and compile it also, then you link vertex and fragment shaders into one *shader program*. That program is the code that will be executed, and it will take you model's attributes and uniforms as its input (like parameters for the function call). But notice that those shaders and program are **already compiled**.

Your fragment shader code works, because instead of passing a uniform variable into it, you literally hard-coded the variable into the code of the shader and compiled it.

The thing is, that vertex shader still expects attributes as input to work with, and you cannot hard-code the variables in it.

Please have a look at the [shader programming tutorials](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-core-tutorial/) to better understand them.

Hope this helps.